# Capturar texto Webrowser

Tags: delphi

Olá, preciso capturar um determinado texto de um site que estou acessando através do `TWebBrowser`, toda vez que logo nesse site interno ele gera um texto  mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX </title>
<body>
<h2> 1678909 <STRONG style="COLOR: #fff">&shy; Acessos</STRONG></P>
```

Preciso capturar somente esse número antes da palavra ACESSOS, como devo     proceder? Lembrando que mesmo eu pegando a posição dele usando Pos(, não adianta porque a cada acesso nessa página a posição do número muda, uma hora está em 200 outra hora em 300 e por ai vai.

Alguém pode me salvar? Lembrando que preciso pegar somente esses números antes do acesso, vai existir outros números na página, mas, o que eu preciso realmente capturar são esses.

Não tenho ideia como fazer isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use as próprias funções nativas do Delphi par isso, segue exemplo:

```
vResultado := Trim(Copy(FONTE_TEXTO,1,Pos(' ',FONTE_TEXTO)));
```

**Entenda o processo:**

```
Trim, vai remover os espaços,
Copy, vai copiar o texto desejado,
FONTE_TEXTO, local onde o texto se encontra,
1, posição de Start da cópia,
Pos, posiciona no final do local ate onde iremos copiar,
' ', é o nosso limitador, ou seja, a posição final da copia,
FONTE_TEXTO, local onde o texto se encontra (nossa fonte do Pos).
```

**Edit:**

Seguindo a explicação que te dei logo acima, basta você alterar a posição de Start da Cópia, observe que copiamos da posição 1 ate posição X com base no separador que é um espaço, agora a posição de Star mudou conforme sua edição, vamos apenas alterar o 1 para uma nova posição de Busca:

Se sabemos que o texto sempre será este e formatado dessa forma, ao invés de informar o 1 vamos buscar com o `Pos('<h2>',FONTE_TEXTO)` a posição inicial!

Para a posição final vamos buscar com o `Pos(' <STRONG ',FONTE_TEXTO)`

Para funcionar, precisamos deletar o restante do texto encontrado, para isso vamos usar uma variável temporária, eu criei um procedimento que você pode usar, seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
procedure frmTeste.BtnApurarResultadoClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  vTemp : String;
begin
  //Procurando o texto, agora com 2 Delimitadores, 1 inicial e 1 final.
  vTemp := Trim(Copy(FONTE_TEXTO,Pos('<h2> ',FONTE_TEXTO) + 5,Pos(' <STRONG ',FONTE_TEXTO)));
  //Agora deletamos o resto do texto após o número.
  Delete(vTemp,Pos(' ',vTemp),Length(vTemp));
  //Variavel vResultado alimentada somente com o número apurado!
  vResultado := vTemp;
end;
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. O Problema é o seguinte, eu estou pegando o código fonte da página do WebBrowser, e colocando em um memo, o código fonte é enorme, entende ? Precisava de um jeito de colocar essa função antes da palavra "Acessos" como eu descrevi na pergunta. Pois aparece da seguinte forma: 16600 Acessos (Preciso pegar somente esse número antes) lembrando que esse número pode chegar a casa dos milhões também e ele muda a todo momento.

Comment: Então amigo, com esse procedimento que passei, não interessa o tamanho do Primeiro conjunto de caracteres pode ser '9384238423423428034234230947345345 Acessos' ele vai capturar tudo antes do Acessos!

Comment: o problema que ANTES desse número de acesso, tem um código gigante entende ? e o numero de ACESSO no meio da página, no caso vou ter que achar a posição EXATA desse número para colocar no Copy, tem um jeito mais fácil de eu achar essa posição ?

Comment: Claro que tem, mas você precisa informar isso, você informou `1678909 Acessos (esse número muda a cada acesso)` então respondi para esse caso, rsrsrsrs

Comment: me desculpe, eu corrigi a pergunta agora. Obrigado, se puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Comment: Segue edição na resposta, vamos aos testes....

Comment: Obrigado @Júnior Moreira

Comment: uma última dúvida @Júnior Moreira, no caso o texto antes do número sempre muda, eu vou ter que fazer ao contrário, por exemplo capturar da palavra ACESSOS (que é após o número) e recortar antes dela, é possível também ? recortar depois dos números até chegar nele ? Esse teu exemplo deu certinho, vou marcar como resposta. Se poder me ajudar em só mais essa dúvida eu agradeço.

Comment: Da sim, observe que aqui `Pos('<h2> ',FONTE_TEXTO) + 5` eu localizo o <h2> e ando 5 posições para frente, posso andar 5 para trás ou mais se precisar!

Comment: Entendi @Júnior Moreira, e esse ESPAÇO que tem entre o STRONG precisa ter mesmo ? no caso eu usaria - 5 então ao invés de + ?

Comment: Exato Positivo ele posiciona para frente e Negativo para trás! O espaço eu apenas deixei pois existe de fato entre ele e o numero, mas não precisa!

Comment: Ok @Júnior Moreira, vou tentar fazer agora, qualquer dúvida eu te aviso, e muito obrigado pela paciência.

Comment: Uma pergunta besta @Júnior Moreira, porque você colocou + 5 no caso se o número tem 7 posições ?

Comment: Não é pergunta besta, observe que `Pos('<h2> ',FONTE_TEXTO) + 5` ele posiciona no inicio do '<h2> ' contando os caracteres é = a 5, ou seja, além de encontrar a posição eu já deixo o cursor após esse texto! rsrsrs Pulo do Gato!

Comment: Entendi @Júnior Moreira, rsrsrs, valeu novamente, estou testando aqui!